# Align arrowhead to right of the super_tooltip in flutter

Tags: flutter, tooltip

I used the super_tooltip package to create my tooltip. Here I want to change the position of the arrowhead of the tooltip. How can I do it? (Like below image - blue color arrow)

```
tooltip = SuperTooltip(
   popupDirection: TooltipDirection.down,
   arrowBaseWidth: 15.0,
   arrowLength: 20.0,
   borderColor: Colors.white,
   borderRadius: 0,
   hasShadow: false,
   minimumOutSidePadding: 10,
   content: new Material(
      child: Text(
         "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscingelitr, "
         softWrap: true,
       )),
   );
```

[image: here I want to show my arrowhead in right]

Comment: can you share any pictures of what actually you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SuperTooltip uses the passed context to determine the target center. So to fix this issue, You can wrap that button in a builder and pass it's context to the show function:

```
Builder(
   builder: (childContext) => IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
         tooltip.show(childContext);
      },
      icon: const Icon(Icons.info_rounded),
   ),
),
```

Read more about [Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html)